# Can Neo4j return additional property maps

Tags: neo4j

I am using the cypher rest api manually for this.

I would like to return the data in a way that is easy to parse.

Here's an example of some data with the same sort of relationships I'm dealing with:

```
(me:Person:Normal),
(dad:Person:Geezer),
(brother:Person:Punk),
(niece:Person:Tolerable),
(daughter:Person:Awesome),
(candy:Rule),
(tv:Rule),
(dad)-[:HAS_CHILD {Num:1}]->(brother),
(dad)-[:HAS_CHILD {Num:2}]->(me),
(me)-[:HAS_CHILD {Num:1}]->(daughter),
(brother)-[:HAS_CHILD {Num:1}]->(niece),
(me)-[:ALLOWS]->(candy),
(me)-[:ALLOWS]->(tv)
```

I want to get all of the HAS_CHILD relationships and if any of those child nodes have :ALLOWS relationships I want the ids of those too.

so if I were to do something like...

```
START n=node({idofdad}) MATCH n-[r?:HAS_CHILD]->h-[?:ALLOWS]->allowed
    WITH n, r, h, collect(ID(allowed)) as allowedIds
    WITH n, r, 
        CASE 
            WHEN h IS NOT NULL THEN [ID(h), LABELS(h), r.Num?, allowedIds] 
            ELSE NULL     
        END as has
RETURN
    LABELS(n) as labels,
    ID(n) as id,
    n as node,
    COLLECT(has) as children;
```

The :HAS_CHILD may not exist, so I have to do this wierd case thing.

The data that comes back is 'ok' but the JSON mapper that I have (Newtonsoft) doesn't make it easy to map an array to an object (meaning I know that array index[0] is ID of the (children) collections.

The results of the above look like this:
    {
      "columns": ["labels", "id", "node", "children"], 
      "data": [
        ["Person", "Geezer"],
        6,
        {},
        [
         [7, ["Person", "Normal"], 2, [2, 1]], 
         [5, ["Person", "Punk"], 1, []]
        ]
      ] 
    }

Since this is more/less a document and it'd be easier to map the 'children' column I'd like to get something that looks like this:

```
{
  "columns": ["labels", "id", "node", "children"], 
  "data": [
    ["Person", "Geezer"],
    6,
    {},
    [
     [
       "id": 7, 
       "labels": ["Person", "Normal"], 
       "ChildNumber": 2, 
       "AllowedIds": [2, 1]
     },
     {
       "id": 5, 
       "labels": ["Person", "Punk"], 
       "ChildNumber": 1, 
       "AllowedIds": []
     }
    ]
  ] 
}
```

I would expect the query to look something like:

```
START n=node({idofdad}) MATCH n-[r?:HAS_CHILD]->h-[?:ALLOWS]->allowed
    WITH n, r, h, collect(ID(allowed)) as allowedIds
    WITH n, r, 
        CASE 
            WHEN h IS NOT NULL THEN 
               { id: ID(h), labels: LABELS(h), ChildNumber: r.Num?, AllowedIds: allowedIds }
            ELSE NULL     
        END as has
RETURN
    LABELS(n) as labels,
    ID(n) as id,
    n as node,
    COLLECT(has) as children;
```

Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: I've ended up keeping the array and wrote a custom object mapper that can map an array to an object ctor.